# How to drop entire row if string of one column contains the word from another column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe contain columns called "product_description" and "manufacturer". I need to remove all rows where 'product_description' has 'manufacturer' in it.

I tried this code:

```
df[~df.product_description.str.contains(df.manufacturer)]
```

and it gave me error

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Is there any other way to do it?
Very much appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need test all values from column `manufacturer` per each value of column `product_description` use `join` with `|` for regex `or`:

```
df[~df.product_description.str.contains('|'.join(data.manufacturer))]
```

Or if need test per rows:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x.product_description not in x.manufacturer, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks. The second method works perfectly!